# How to scan more than one location at the same time with ClamAV

Tags: command-line, clamav

When scanning my computer with ClamAV what I normally do is execute something like:

```
sudo clamscan -r --detect-pua --infected --bell / | tee ClamscanLog16.txt
```

But sometimes I am scanning more than one item (file or folder), and when those items are not in the same folder/location as each other, things become a bit more difficult for I have to execute a similar version of the command above for several different locations.

So really what my question is, is there a way in a single command to scan more than one item in different locations in your file system at the same time?

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
```

**Package Information:**

```
clamav:
  Installed: 0.98.6+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.10.1
  Candidate: 0.98.6+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.10.1
  Version table:
 *** 0.98.6+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.10.1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.98.4+dfsg-2 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need *any special software* to do that, just the base operating system: **multi-tasking is built-in!**

Just do:

```
sudo clamscan -r --detect-pua --infected --bell /var > /var/log/clamav.log.scan-var.txt &
sudo clamscan -r --detect-pua --infected --bell /bin > /var/log/clamav.log.scan-bin.txt &
sudo clamscan -r --detect-pua --infected --bell /media/Samba/MumsDrive > /var/log/clamav.log.Scan-mum.txt &
```

and then from 3 different terminals you can see these at work:

```
tail --follow /var/log/clamav.log.scan-var.txt
```

in one terminal, and

```
tail --follow /var/log/clamav.log.Scan-bin.txt
```

in another etc...

So I would `sudo apt-get purge parallel` and keep my OS as close to the base as possible!  Less software means a stabler system!  **;-)**

**Rant:** This is the 21st century you know!  The times of single-tasking single-user systems like the [Colossus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossus_computer), the Apollo [guidance computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Guidance_Computer), the [Apple II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_II), the [Commodore 64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_64), [...](http://www.computerhistory.org/timeline/?category=cmptr) are over!

Answer (score 1):

1. Install *parallel*

   parallel - build and execute shell command lines from standard input in parallel

   ```
    sudo apt-get install parallel
   ```
2. Use *parallel*

   ```
    (echo "sudo clamscan -r --detect-pua --infected --bell <first_location>"; echo "sudo clamscan -r --detect-pua --infected --bell <second_location>") | parallel
   ```